# LibGDX - Multiple actors receiving key events

Tags: input, libgdx

I have more than one actor (for a local coop game) that need to receive key events (e.g. Player 1 uses arrow keys, Player 2 uses WASD etc...). If I just add Actors to a Stage, they don't receive key events through the InputListener, and if I do this:

```
stage.setKeyboardFocus(p1);
stage.setKeyboardFocus(p2);
```

Only Player 2 receives key events, of course. How can I have two (or more) actors receive key events?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Group or a Table which are actors that can contain other actors, and add the actors

```
Gdx.setInputProcessor(stage);
group = new Group();
group.addActor(actor1);
group.addActor(actor2);

group.addListener(new InputListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode){
    if (keycode == Keys.A){
       update(actor1)
    }
    if (keycode == Keys.LEFT{
       update(actor2)
    }
    return true;
    });

stage.addActor(group);
stage.setKeyboardFocus(group);
```

Comment: Just to let you know: Actors are automatically added to a group called root inside the Stage. And the Stage extends the InputAdapter so you don't nedd to add the listener to that group, you have direct access to that methods.

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx `Stage` extends `InputAdapter`, which gives you access to the methods `keyDown(int keyCode)` and `keyUp(int keyCode)`. If you set the `Stage` as your `InputProcessor` by using: `Gdx.setInputProcessor(stage);` you can handle key inputs in the `Stage`.
Some Pseudocode:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case Input.Keys.A:
         player2.moveLeft();
    case Input.Keys.NUMPAD_4:
         player1.moveLeft();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's curious that nobody mentioned [InputMultiplexer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html). Try it for your situation.

Comment: He has only one InputProcessor - stage. So he can't apply InputMultiplexer in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Instead of setting the keyboard focus to the individual Actors, set it to a common actor, and then just add a listener to that actor. E.G.:

```
public class Scene extends Stage
{
    public Scene()
    {
        setKeyboardFocus(getRoot()); // getRoot() returns the parent actor group
        addActor(new Player(1));
        addActor(new Player(2));
    }
}

public class Player extends Actor
{
    public Player(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.getRoot().addListener(inputListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not set it to the root group directly. Set your stage as the inputListener, like i suggested. So your stage can handle the inputs and give it to the affected Actor